# C#Regex change some text after specific regex match

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have this :

```
string text = "My parameter @1, and my other parameter @10"
```

how can i replace @1 to some value?

when I do `text= text.replace("@1", "value");`

I have `text = "My parameter value, and my other parameter value0"`

The bad thing is that @10 has changed.

I had the idea of using regex to find the correct value to modify :

```
string pattern = "@1[^0-9]";

Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(text, "value");
```

this time I have "My parameter value and my other parameter @10"
This time the coma ',' was removed.

So how can I replace properly the @1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `\b` with your regex to achieve what you want:

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"@1\b", "sometext");
                                 ^^  here
```